# Why the loop is taking so long and so slow?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I created a new class for the testing:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using OpenHardwareMonitor.Hardware;
using System.Diagnostics;
using DannyGeneral;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Threading;
using System.Management;
using System.Globalization;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace HardwareMonitoring
{


    class CpuUsages
    {
        public static string processes;

        public static string cputest()
        {
            PerformanceCounter cpuCounter = new PerformanceCounter();
            cpuCounter.CategoryName = "Processor";
            cpuCounter.CounterName = "% Processor Time";
            cpuCounter.InstanceName = "_Total";

            var unused = cpuCounter.NextValue(); // first call will always return 0
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000); // wait a second, then try again
            //Console.WriteLine("Cpu usage: " + cpuCounter.NextValue() + "%");
            processes = "Cpu usage: " + cpuCounter.NextValue() + "%";
            return processes;
        }
    }
}
```

Then in form1 i added a new timer set it to 1000ms enable it when running the program and inside the timer tick event i did:

```
private void timer3_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Process[] processes = Process.GetProcesses();

            foreach (Process process in processes)
            {
                CpuUsages.cputest();
                cpuusage = CpuUsages.processes;
                label26.Text = cpuusage;
            }
        }
```

This way it's working very slow take a long time to make the loop foreach.
In general i wanted to loop over each running process and get it's cpuusage.

But if i remove the foreach loop like this:

```
private void timer3_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
                Process[] processes = Process.GetProcesses();          
                CpuUsages.cputest();
                cpuusage = CpuUsages.processes;
                label26.Text = cpuusage;
        }
```

Then it will work fast i will see in label26 the cpuusage updating eavery second.
The problem is that it will show the cpuusage for only on process.

What can i do to solve it ? 
In general i wanted to create automatic number of labels for each process in the list and display each process cpuusage. But it's so slow and take so long when i use the foreach loop.

Is there any way to solve it ?

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
foreach (Process process in processes)
{
    CpuUsages.cputest();
    cpuusage = CpuUsages.processes;
    label26.Text = cpuusage;
}
```

will make your program sleeps for 1 second * (number of processes running on your machine). No wonder the `foreach` loop is slow.

Remove those `Sleep` calls, and have your loop running in another Thread, avoiding slowing down the User interface.

Also I don't see why you are iterating over the `processes` returned by `Process.GetProcesses()` : you are not using them.

Comment: quantdev can you show me how to do it at least the part of using the processes ? " Also I don't see why you are iterating over the processes returned by Process.GetProcesses() : you are not using them " i want to iterting over all the running processes to get each process cpu uage. How can i do it ?

Comment: quantdev i must use the thread.sleep(1000); in the new class if not it won't give the correct cpu usage value/s.